# How can I play a video in a Godot game?

Tags: video, godot

I'd like to know if and how it is possible for me to play a video in my Godot game. Specifically I'd like to know what video file format I need to use and what code I have to write to play that video back fullscreen.

Comment: -1 "This question does not show any research effort". You obviously did not [search the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=godot+engine+how+to+play+video).

Comment: I tried searching, but can't find anything.

Comment: ryank135 , please show / tell us what you have tried to upload the videos ,

Comment: "Yes or no" questions are generally a bad fit for this site, so instead I have edited your question to ask _how_. I did, however, assume you want to play the video back fullscreen. If you want to do something else, like play it on the surface of some 3D object, you should edit the question to account for that.

Comment: This question is a lot more useful with the amendments.

Comment: Please also note that while alex quotes a lesser known search engine, the same phrase on Google provides official documentation supporting the accepted answer in the first result. Try a little research, and tell us what you have tried next time; it can really counter those down votes.

Answer (score 2):

Godot has a [`VideoPlayer`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_videoplayer.html) API that is suitable for this purpose.

Once you create a `VideoPlayer` node, you can use the `set_stream` function to assign the desired video stream. You can load such a stream using the `load` function: `load("some/path/to/your/video.ogv")`.

Note that `VideoPlayer` *only* supports the OGV Theora format.